# Issue with Lagrange interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, polynomial-math

I'm having an issue completing this Lagrange function and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

I keep getting 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions' error. I assume this is because I'm not moving through the array correctly. I've tried a combination of things but seem to continue coming back to this error.

```
function y = lagrange(X, Y, x)
n = length(X);
if n ~= length(Y)
 error('X and Y must have the same length.');
end
y = zeros(size(x)); 
for i = 1:n 
  L = ones(size(x)); 
    for j = [1:i-1 i+1:n] 
      if (i~=j)
       L(1:i-1, i+1:n) = L(1:i-1, i+1:n).*(x-X(j))/(X(i)-X(j));
      end
    end
  y = y+Y(i)*L(1:i-1);
end
```

Comment: Look at what size you expect for x vs X. You set up L to be the size of x but then index into it with values up to the length of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function below is what you need.

```
function y = lagrangian(X, Y, x)
if length(X) ~= length(Y); error('X and Y must have the same length.'); end
y = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:length(X)
   L = ones(size(x));
   for j = [1:i-1 i+1:length(X)]
       L = L.*(x-X(j))/(X(i)-X(j));
   end
   y = y+Y(i)*L;
end
```